# Go Back to the Previous Location on Previous Page when Clicking Browser Back Button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, browser, back-button

This is what I want to implement:

On page a, click the link, go to page b,showing everything on page b from the beginning. Click browser back button, it goes back to page a and showing contents from the link position.

This is what I got now:

It happens between two aspx pages,

1、On the first page, http://xxxx/default.aspx#project/page/home, there is a link <  a href="#page/test" >TEST< / a >

2、So When I click this link, it will jump to http://xxxx/default.aspx#project/page/test. But it seems like the browser remembers the link position on page/home and directly jump to the same position on page/test,instead of showing all the contents from the very beginning.

3、When I click browser back button, to the previous page, it also cannot go back to that link position.

Additional information:
I changed the < a href="#page/test" >TEST< / a> to < a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215449/browser-does-not-remember-position-of-page-last-viewed" >TEST< / a >, it worked just fine. So I think it is because of the aspx pages and the hashtag.

I have tried this, it will cause showing two pages at the same time(one on the left and one on the right)
[Take User Back to Where They Scrolled to on previous page when clicking Browser Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168861/take-user-back-to-where-they-scrolled-to-on-previous-page-when-clicking-browser)

Please help, thank you.

Comment: `http://xxxx/default.aspx#project/page/home` and `http://xxxx/default.aspx#project/page/test`  are both the same page - default.aspx

Comment: @JenR, Thank you so much for the reply. Do you happen to know a way to implement what I wanted? even they are one page.

Answer (score 0):

To use an `<a>` tag to re-position the page, you need to have an element with an `id` attribute that matches the text following `#` in the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 id="thetop">Top of page!</h2>

<p>Text here</p>

<a href="#thetop">Go to top</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Before HTML5, this was done with another `<a>` that included a `name` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a name="thetop">Top of page!</a>

<p>Text here</p>

<a href="#thetop">Go to top</a>
</body>
</html>
```